# Rspec let hash key unexpected =>, expecting '}'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, let

I am confusing in using ruby hash key format and `let`.

This works in normal case.

```
{
           "id" => 1,
  "description" => "test 3",
   "difficulty" => { "id" => 1, "description" => "easy" },
}
```

but fails in `let` block

Here's the code:

```
describe 'incorrect_question' do

  let(:wrong_question1) {
             "id" => 1,
    "description" => "test 3",
     "difficulty" => { "id" => 1, "description" => "easy" },
  }
  it 'does something' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

It results in the following exception:

```
syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
                  "id" => 1,
                         ^
```

Comment: I think, problem is that you need to move your hash to one more `{}` and remove `,`  after `.. "easy" },`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: By the way, you don't even have `"id" => 3` in the code.

Comment: @sawa sorry, I extract the wrong error segment. I've modified it.

Comment: @AlexGolubenko that works, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your block spans for more than one line use `do`/`end`.
2. When above is done you'll see that you're missing both the opening `{` and closing `}` of the hash:

   ```
   let(:wrong_question1) do
     {
                "id" => 1,
       "description" => "test 3",
       "difficulty" => { "id" => 1, "description" => "easy" }
     }
   end
   ```